# Algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory, rational-numbers, algebraic-groups

I am trying to prove 2 statements:

1. $\bar{\mathbb{Q}} _\mathbb{R}\subset \mathbb{R}$
2. $\bar{\mathbb{R}} _\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{C}$

For (1), I have come up with a few examples such as $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{R}$ which are algebraic in $\mathbb{Q}$, since we have $f=X^2-2,g=X^2-3\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$ and $f(\sqrt{2})=0$ and $g(\sqrt{3})=0$.

Then, we see that $a+b,a-b,ab\in{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}}_\mathbb{R}$ and $\frac{a}{b}\in{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}}_\mathbb{R}$ for $b\neq0$.

Is this enough to claim that $\bar{\mathbb{Q}} _\mathbb{R}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$? I feel like this is not enough since I have not explored every element of $\mathbb{R}$ which are algebraic in $\mathbb{Q}$.

For (2), how do I show that the inclusion works both ways, ${\bar{\mathbb{R}}}_\mathbb{C}\subset\mathbb{C}$ and ${\bar{\mathbb{R}}}_\mathbb{C}\supset\mathbb{C}$ such that LHS and RHS are equal, i.e. ${\bar{\mathbb{R}}}_\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{C}$?

NB: By $\bar{K}_F$, I mean algebraic closure of $K$ in $F$

Comment: What does $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\mathbb{R}}$ mean? If you mean the relative algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then it's a subset by definition.

Comment: It's the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @krn08 If it's the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then you have $1$ by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\overline{K}_F$ is the algebraic closure of $K$ in $F$; so it's obvious that $K \subset F$.

So for **(2)**, to prove $\overline{\mathbb{R}}_\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{C}$; all we need to prove is that $\mathbb{C} \subset \overline{\mathbb{R}}_\mathbb{C}$.

Take $a + bi \in \mathbb{C}$; and it's easy to see that this is a solution to the equation $0 = x^2 - 2ax + a^2 + b^2 \in \mathbb{R}[x]$

---

For **(1)**, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number

It's a well known fact that $\pi \in \mathbb{R}$ is **not** a solution to any equations with rational coefficient; hence $\pi \notin \overline{\mathbb{Q}}_\mathbb{R}$.

So $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_\mathbb{R} \subsetneq \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: [@user49685](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/49685/user49685) Is the part with a complex number and a real polynomial used to show that $\mathbb{C}\subset \bar{\mathbb{R}}_\mathbb{C}$ or $\bar{\mathbb{R}_\mathbb{C}}\subset \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: It's relatively difficult to show that $\pi$ is non-algebraic. $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(10^k)!}$ is much easier by comparison. An existential proof is also pretty easy: it's not hard to see that the algebraic closure of a countable field is countable.

Comment: @krn08 It's to show that every complex number is a solution to some polynomial equation with real coefficients; i.e $\mathbb{C} \subset \overline{\mathbb{R}}_\mathbb{C}$.